# Not found module error when I tried importing module what I made

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, settings, visual-studio-code

I tried to import myPackage's myModule what I made to main.
The Directory structure is like below

```
#Directory structure
test02
└myPackage
│     └myModule.py
│     └__init__.py
└myView
      └main.py
```

but it has ModuleNotFoundError like screen shot I attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILZQe.png)

```
#main 
from myPackage import myModule

myModule.printTest()
```

```
#myModule
def printTest():
    print('test')
```

I know one solution and it is that I input path by myself
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qXvT.png)

```
#main 
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/VScode/vscode_python/test02/')
from myPackage import myModule

myModule.printTest()
```

```
#myModule
def printTest():
    print('test')
```

but I think it is not smart way.

I would like to know if there is a way to set the vs code so that the path is automatically added.

Comment: Hi Leo, could you insert the code in the post please, instead of images? It would make your question more readable and also searchable. Thank you.

Comment: Thank  you for your comment. I added the code

Answer (score 0):

You can either copy-paste myModule to the same location as main.py.  And simply use :

```py
import myModule
```

Or copy paste myPackage to the location said earlier. And use:

```py
from myPackage import myModule
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because MyModule.py is not in the same folder than main.py.

Or you have to put them in the same folder or you can add the path of MyModule.py in the sys.path variable:

```
import os,sys,inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
print(sys.path)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir+'\\MyPackage')
print(sys.path)
```

and then import MyModule

Comment: Hmmmm....

Is there any way to solve the problem without directly input the path while maintaining the current directory structure?

For example, change the settings of vscode.